# How to get page to update with new records from server without a route change?

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember app that uses server-side storage. In the products route, I have a list of products that I display in my product route (which are fetched in the usual way upon entering the route)

```
   {{#each item in sortedProducts}}

   {{/each}}
```

....
**fetch**

```
App.ProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function(){
         return Ember.RSVP.hash({ 
            store: this.store.find('product'),
            //other code ommitted

         })
      }
})
```

In the controller, I do the sorting

```
sortProperties: ['date:desc'] //dated added
sortedProducts: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortProperties'),
```

This works, however, I give the user the option to filter the records displayed. Upon clicking a button, an action is called that queries the server for a subset of records (it doesn't just filter the records that are already in the store cache)

```
 actions: {
 filterByPriceAndColor: function(){
    this.store.find('product', {price: pricevariable, color: colorvariable});
 }
 }
```

This queries and returns the desired records, but the list on the page isn't updated i.e. the list on the page still displays all the records that are fetched upon application load.

Question: how do I get the page to update with the new records fetched from the server without a route change, (and will the solution integrate with the computed sort that already exists for ordering the entries by date)

Comment: is ember-data a hard requirement for your project?

Comment: yes it is, but if it's possible to make the query and update the template without using Ember data for this particular query, then I would consider it.

Comment: Ah, the interop w/ ED might be out of my current scope. Ideally if you could access the identity map inside ED and push items into it you'd be golden with vanilla $.ajax (I'm just not sure how to do this myself yet)

Comment: There's some information about how it might be done here http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/models/frequently-asked-questions/ but I can't figure out how to integrate it into my app

Comment: The `store.find` in your action returns a promise that will be fulfilled after the communication with the server is done or rejected if it fails. Your problem is, that you do nothing with this promise or respectively the received data.

Comment: @kunerd yes, I agree.  that's the point of the question. from that context, how do I update the template with the received data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update your `model` from an action (or anywhere else) you simple need to set a new value for it and Ember will to the hard work for you.

In your case it should look like this:

```
actions: {
  filterByPriceAndColor: function() {
    var promise = this.store.find('product', {price: pricevariable, color: colorvariable});

    var self = this;
    promise.then(function(data) {
      self.set('model', data);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is a JSBin demonstrating how it works: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/walunokaro/3/edit