# Observing RecordArrays in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this setup right now:

```
App.Workspace = Em.Object.extend({
  users: null,
  usersChanged: Em.observer('users',function() {
    console.log('Users Updated!');
  }),
  ...
  initListeners: function() {
    var self = this;
    someObject.on('someEvent', function() {
      ...
      console.log('before set');
      self.set('users', self.store.all('users'));
    });
  }
});
```

I only get the output "before set", but not "Users updated!"

What am I missing?

Comment: Store returns a promise, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685344/how-to-get-page-to-update-with-new-records-from-server-without-a-route-change/30693750#30693750 for a solution.

Comment: emberjs docs about `all()`: "This method returns a filtered array"

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I tried a similar thing and it worked. Can you provide a JSBin for your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use

```
Em.observer('users.[]',function() {...});
```

to observe RecordArray. Look at jsbin demonstration for you. http://jsbin.com/noxijuloqi/edit?html,js,output

2) Make sure you've injected store into your Object properly, so `self.store` is not `undefined`.

3) Also you should correct typo

```
self.store.all('user');
```

instead

```
self.store.all('users');
```